# How to pause on self-made player

Tags: javascript

I made a music player using javascript with mainly code taken on the internet, and it's working pretty good.. except I can't pause the music, it just restarts from the beginning of the song everytime I click on the button. I want it to be played onclick, and stopped when reclicked, but I don't know how to... Hope you guys can help! :)

```
        var audiotypes={
        "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
        "mp4": "audio/mp4",
        "ogg": "audio/ogg",
        "wav": "audio/wav"
    }

    function ss_soundbits(sound){
        var audio_element = document.createElement('audio')
        if (audio_element.canPlayType){
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var source_element = document.createElement('source')
                source_element.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                    source_element.setAttribute('type', audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                    audio_element.appendChild(source_element)
            }
            audio_element.load()
            audio_element.playclip=function(){
                audio_element.pause()
                audio_element.currentTime=0
                audio_element.play()
            }
            return audio_element
        }
    }
```

This is how I call it at the end of my html file :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >var clicksound  = ss_soundbits("./snd/prudence.mp3")
```

I just linked it to my button which is an svg image via this line :

```
onclick="clicksound.playclip()"
```

Do you guys have any idea ? 
I also would like, if I can in any way, stop the music via a mute button, if you also happen to have an idea on how to do that...

Thank you guys in advance for helping! :)

Comment: I strongly suspect `audio_element.currentTime=0` is your culprit.

Comment: When deleting it, the music never stops, it just keeps on playing...

Comment: Your play button should `.play()`, pause should `.pause()`, and stop would `.pause()` and `.currentTime = 0`, I think. How many controls do you have?

Comment: One actually, I'd like to click one button to play, and click the same button to pause! except here, it just rerolls the music!

Comment: I think most players use two buttons for play/pause, they just put them in the same place and make sure only one is visible at a time.

Comment: What can I do then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [DEMO](http://glx.s3.amazonaws.com/audioPlayer.htm)

I tried the original function but it wasn't working for me so I just made an audio player from plain JS. Study this audioPlayer, take it apart, research it piece by piece and you can advance to better coding. Cutting and pasting is very limited, don't worry about trying and failing, because after 2 years, I still fail on a daily basis.

### JS

```
function playAudio() {
    if (audioBox.paused) {
            audioBox.load();
      audioBox.play();
            playBtn.classList.remove("play");
        playBtn.classList.add("pause");

    } else { 
        audioBox.pause();
                playBtn.classList.remove("pause");
            playBtn.classList.add("play");
    }
}

function stopAudio() {
     audioBox.pause();
     audioBox.currentTime = 0;
     playBtn.classList.remove("pause");
     playBtn.classList.add("play");
}

function muteAudio() {
            audioBox.muted = !audioBox.muted;
            mute.classList.toggle("vol", "novol");
}
```

### HTML

```
<header>&nbsp;</header>
<main>
<audio id="audioBox" controls>
    <source src="https://glvid.s3.amazonaws.com/jwp/test/111.m4a" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
<div id="audioPanel">
    <button id="playPause" class="play" onclick="playAudio(); return false;"></button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stopAudio(); return false;"></button>
    <button id="mute" class="vol" onclick="muteAudio(); return false;"></button>
</div>
</main>
<footer>&nbsp;</footer>
```

### CSS

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; font: 500 16px/1.5 Xonsolas; height: 100%; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; text-decoration: none; list-style-type: none; }
body { background-color: #333; font-size: 15px; font-size: .95rem;
color: #FFF; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
main { width: 100%; height: 101%; color: #fff; background: #222; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: center; align-content: center; position: relative; }
#audioBox { width: 20%; height: 5.5em; }
#audioPanel { width: 20%; height: 50px; display: table-row; border: 1px solid #777; background: transparent; border-radius: 12px; }
#playPause, #stop, #mute { font-size: 1.5rem; color: #0FF; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto; border: 1px solid #00d; background: #333; display: table-cell; height: 50px; width: 50px; outline: none; }
#playPause { border-bottom-left-radius: 12px; border-top-left-radius: 12px; padding-bottom: 5px; }
#stop:after { content: '\25A0' }
.vol:after { content: '\2261' }
.novol:after { content: '__' }
#playPause:hover, #stop:hover, #mute:hover { color: #000; background: #0DD; }
.play:after { content: '\25B6' }
.pause:after { content: '\25AE\25AE'; font-size: 1.25rem; }
```

Comment: thank you zer00ne for your help!! :) it's not working though, I don't know how to link your script to my audio file..

Comment: Try replacing `playclip` with `playAudio`.  `stopAudio()` can standalone.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you couldn't make it work because I neglected to use the correct selectors for the buttons, I forgot the '.' for each.

Comment: I made all the changes but it still doesn't work, there's something I still don't get is how the script and my file is connected! Am I to still use the original script I posted up there ? Are those suppose to work together ?

Comment: Replace this:`           audio_element.playclip=function(){
                audio_element.pause()
                audio_element.currentTime=0
                audio_element.play()`

Comment: How much time have you had with JS?

Comment: A little really I'm a beginner :x .. I have to replace 'audio_element.playclip=function(){ audio_element.pause() audio_element.currentTime=0 audio_element.play()' from my original script and replace with yours? If that's it, I made it, still doesn't work.. once again thank you for helping i'm really lost in javascript.. I can handle jquery better though..

Comment: Oh, well ok that'll be easier then. Look back on this post and if you don't get an answer within 24 hrs by then, I'll be happy to help you. I gotta go to sleep.

Comment: and it's working !! :D I did play around with your code a little bit, actually just changed the html and css a bit to adapt it but it's working exactly as I wanted it to work ! Thank you so much for your advices that I will keep in mind for sure !